How to reset Krita's "Download as Remote Source" default option on pasting images?
When using Krita, I pasted an image, and it asked if I wanted to download the file from remote source, copy it from local, or paste from bitmap (or something along those lines). I clicked Download from Remote Source and then toggled "Remember my decision", but the paste isn't working and I don't know how to undo that option. How can I reset the setting responsible for this?
Semi-relevant screenshot: The dialog that now appears when I try to paste an image from the web:


It might not be the most elegant, but I did Settings > Reset All Settings > Restarted Krita and it fixed it
